# How to change location of ".docker" directory

Tags: docker

When I start docker on windows, it says:

> Downloading C:\Users\dhblah.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.11.0/boot2docker.iso...

How do I change location of `.docker` directory to, say, `C:\dev\.docker`?

Answer (score 1):

`DOCKER_OPTS=-g /your/folder/here`

-> restart the docker daemon with these settings.

this changes the directory where images are saved.

Now, you're running boot2docker o Windows I presume; boot2docker is a Linux VM. The docker images will be saved in the VM.

If what you're trying to do is change where the boot2docker image is deployed by your VM engine, refer to the engine you use (is it VirtualBox?)